# Como retornar tamanho de vetor com sizeof()?

Tags: c

Este é o código que  estou usando, mas o retorno da função tamVet  não é o tamanho do vetor, e sim o tamanho do ponteiro sobre ele mesmo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tamVet(int *vet){
    int tam;
    tam = sizeof(vet) / sizeof(vet[0]);
    return tam; //Está retornando 1 invés de 10, o número de elementos de vetor[10]
}

int main(){
    int vetor[10];
    printf("%i", tamVetor(vetor));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Como retornar tamanho de vetor" eu acho uma pergunta interessante. Mas no seu caso, pq faz questão que seja com `sizeof()`?

Comment: Desconheço outra forma de pegar tamanho de um vetor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Em C, assim que você passa um array para uma função o array "decai" para um ponteiro para seu primeiro elemento. O comprimento do vetor é esquecido e a única maneira de passá-lo pra função é usando um argumento separado. Por exemplo, o `main` recebe um argumento `argc` além do vetor `argv`.

No seu caso, se a única coisa que você quiser fazer é criar algo pra ter que digitar menos acho que dá pra resolver usando macros ao invés de funções.

```
#define TAMVET(vet) (sizeof(vet)/sizeof((vet)[0]))
```

Comment: Entendi. Não conhecia esta forma hugomg, obrigado

Comment: Tome *bastante* cuidado com macros. É extremamente fácil dar um tiro no pé com eles.

Comment: Certo, estou estudando sobre eles agora :)